# How to catch Enter key and change event to Tab in Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a swing application with multiple jtextfield on it. How do you replace the function of the enter key wherein when you press the Enter key, it will transfer to the nextfocusable component just like the tab key? I dont want to put a keylistener on each jtextfield.

Comment: you really want to _replace_ the default action (which is to notify its action/Listeners, aka: commit)? Or commit + focusTransfer?

Comment: What I want my program to happen is, after i fill the jtextfield with the data required for that field, I will press enter then the focus will jump on the second jtextfield (which I assigned as the next focusable component) just like when you press the tab key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`Container.setFocusTraversalKeys`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setFocusTraversalKeys%28int,%20java.util.Set%29):

```
Container root = ...
// pressed TAB, control pressed TAB
Set<AWTKeyStroke> defaultKeys = root.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
// since defaultKeys is unmodifiable
Set<AWTKeyStroke> newKeys = new HashSet<>(defaultKeys); 
newKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed ENTER"));
root.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newKeys);
```

For more information, take a look at the [Focus Subsystem tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can call:

```
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.focusNextComponent();
```

but you will have to register a single ActionListener with all your JTextFields.